# Preprocessor macros in the C++ standard

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I was surprised to see that `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is described as being a preprocessor macro that is defined in the C++11 standard. Is this something of an exception, or do the new C++ standards really cover the preprocessor step?

To me the preprocessor is a practically language of its own, and the tendency nowadays seems to be to discourage using it.

Comment: btw, another example of macros in the standard is [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), though inherited from c.

Comment: Which I think probably cuts to the gist of it. C doesn't support templates so it's preprocessing or nothing for things like compile-time inclusion decisions. C++ seeks to maintain a reasonably close relationship with C, so the preprocessor isn't going anywhere regardless of its relative merits.

Comment: `#include` is a preprocessor directive. (Just sayin').

Comment: Relevant: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/c11-defects-initialization-of-atomic_flag/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course the C++ standard covers the preprocessor; in fact, there's [a whole chapter on it in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp). The [third and fourth phases of translation](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases) deal primarily with the preprocessor.

The C++ standard also specifies [many predefined macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros); `assert` is also a macro as are the atomic initializers as you've discovered.

There are still situations where macros are useful, but many of the most common use cases are better covered by features of recent C++ standards, such as `constexpr` functions/variables.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that the C++ standard doesn't cover the preprocessor, but rather I was surprised that the new additions (C++11 and later) still add things that rely on it, when it's not really part of "modern" C++ (or at least that seems to be how it's presented).

Comment: It is absolutely part of "modern" C++; but as I mention in the answer some of the previously common uses for macros (which are only part of what the preprocessor does) are better addressed by other features from C++11 onward. That might make it seem less modern, but that's mostly because it won't be the appropriate tool _as often_.